# Replace screen process from within screen

Tags: shell, process, zsh, gnu-screen

I have configured my shell to `exec screen` when it starts, unless it's already running within a screen session. So in a TTY, the process tree will look like something like this:

```
login───screen───screen───zsh.
```

In almost every case, this is what I want, but sometimes I would like to run something without screen, and I would like to do so without changing my usual setup. I'm looking for a command that replaces the topmost screen process with somehting else, e.g., a shell, like this:

```
login───bash,
```

without having to log back out and make temporary changes to my `.zshrc` or use `chsh`.

Answer (score 1):

You sould start the screen session in you `.zshrc` without `exec`, just `screen`. `exec` replaces the current process with the new one. So, you will never get back to the original process because it doesn't exist anymore.

If started without `exec`, `pstree` would then look similar to this (I added `-p` to pstree to show the PIDs for comprehension):

```
|-login(857)---zsh(31597)---screen(1105)---screen(1108)---zsh(1109)-+-pstree(1209)
$ echo $$
1109
```

We are now in the child process of the `screen`, hence inside the `screen`. When you now want to execute something outside of the `screen` close the `screen` or detach for it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>. Again `pstree`:

```
|-screen(1108)---zsh(1109)
|-login(857)---zsh(31597)-+-pstree(1481)
$ echo $$
31597
```

The first line is the detachted `screen` with a shell running inside, the second one the currently running shell (Where we are now). As you see the `$$` variable contains the PID of the first `zsh` process.

To go back into the screen, simply call:

```
screen -r
```

It looks now similar as in the first scenario:

```
|-screen(1108)---zsh(1109)-+-pstree(2118)
|-login(857)---zsh(31597)---screen(2112)
$ echo $$
1109
```

Notice the PID: I'm back in the shell that is a child of `screen` (1108). That `screen` process (1108) is not anymore a child process of the original screen (1105), because that process doesn't exist anymore. That's why 1108 got reparented (his parent is now `init` with PID 1). At the point where I called `screen -r` to reattach back, a new screen process was created with a new PID (2112). Those `screen` process talk over simple unix sockets or via named pipes with each other.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend rather than replacing the shell with screen just having it launch or attach based off of whether or not a screen is running then you have the freedom to detatch with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> - <kbd>d</kbd>

```
if [[ ! $(screen -ls 2>&1) =~ .*No.Sockets.* ]] ; then 
  screen -U -x 
else 
  echo 'No existing screen sockets found, launching screen!'; screen -U -S session -s `which zsh`
fi
```

Should stick ↑ in either ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc then set your user's default shell to bash.  This will fork new zsh processes everytime you create new screen windows and always reattach you to your screen session or start a new one if it isn't running.  That way you could detatch from screen and run things outside of it.  And if for instance you wanted to move one of the processes that was already in the screen you could do so with something like [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr).

Answer (score 0):

The following method is maybe a bit tricky but can be a solution to your question.

You might create a duplicate of the user by editing the /etc/passwd file and duplicate the line of your user. Only change the username (first field). Set a password for your 'new' user by `passwd newuser`. Finally change your `.zshrc` and replace the `exec screen` with a check on the username:

```
if [ "`id -un`" != "newuser" ]
then
    exec screen
fi
```

When you want to have a session without `exec screen` you can login with the alternate user which is actually the same as your regular user.

Perhaps there are better alternatives for what you are trying to achieve but this might help you...